# Sample Variance Divided by Sample Size?

Tags: probability, statistics

In my statistics book I found an example comparing paired samples. They computed the mean of the difference, $\bar{D} = 10.27$ and the sample standard deviation (or sample standard error) from the difference column as follows:

$s_{\bar{D}}^{2} = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{11} (D_{i}-\bar{D})^{2}}{11}$

but then they divided $s_{\bar{D}}$ by the sample size **again**:

$s_{\bar{D}}^{2} = \frac{s_{\bar{D}}^{2}}{11}$

and finally took the square root of $s_{\bar{D}}^{2}$ to find the standard deviation.

**My Question:** Why does the book divide by the sample size a second time?

Below is the data from the book, and a snippet of R code I used to recreate the example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are basically the statistics of a sample mean estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first division leads to the sample variance, and its square root to the sample standard deviation.

The second division and its square root leads to the sample [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean) and so is suitable for comparing differences in means